# Json.put() function puts double quotes automatically

Tags: android, json

I am preparing a json object to be sent over a webservice , I am trying to put a list of String in the object, Something like this:

`["24348f08-92f4-481a-9a36-ed0d533ca4f3", "24348f08-92f4-481a-9a36-ed0d533ca4f3"]`

What i have done:

```
    sendData.put("SpecializationAlert",Specialization);
```

sendData is a json object and Specialization is a String array, the result when i log this is:

`"[\"24348f08-92f4-481a-9a36-ed0d533ca4f3\",\"24348f08-92f4-481a-9a36-ed0d533ca4f3\"]"`

Comment: What you're actually doing is adding a `Specialization.toString()` return value as string, and it gets escaped properly.

Comment: Could you please clarify what is `Specialization` type? It's unclear -  my understanding: `String[]`, @allprog assumed it's a single `String`...

Comment: String[] Specialization = new String[SpecialisatoinLength];

Comment: The answer by @allprog was updated according to the clarification, enjoy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Specialization` is put in the JSON as a `toString()`-ed object. You may create a JSONArray from it first and then include it in the JSONObject:

```
sendData.put("SpecializationAlert",new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(Specialization)));
```

Comment: What if OP actually wants to transmit a quote character inside one of the strings? You're solving the wrong problem here.

Comment: Well, the OP does not want to transmit those characters. READ THE QUESTION

Comment: I did. OP only gives an example, so you can't tell if quotes will ever appear there - it's undefined. `Specialization` is String array, according to question, I suppose OP wants to convert it to JSON array of string values. OP incorrectly uses the API, what you propose is a hack, not a solution.

Comment: Actually the question itself is ill-formed, to be honest :)